# Elements with absolute position always appearing at the bottom of the view on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, hybrid-mobile-app

I have elements with a predefined positions `top` and `left` and I'm trying to add them in the view in their appropriate position but when I test it on my phone they are always appearing at the bottom of the view. I tested it with the Chrome debugger and it's working as a charm but not on my smartphone.

```css
.device-list-item1{
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
 }
 .button1{
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    padding: 20px 5px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid $color-light-grey;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px $color-light-grey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: $color-se-logo-green;
    max-height: 100px;
    background: $color-white;
    font-size: 14px;
    .device-icon {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      background-size: contain;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-image: url("./img/DeviceIcon.png");
      color: $color-se-logo-green;
      height: 30px;
      width: 30px;
    }
    .dashboard-device-container {
      display: table;
      >div {
        display: table-cell;
      }
      >span {
    display: block;
      }
      > div.icons {
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
      > div.name {
        width: 99%;
        line-height: 20px;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
    <div id="device-list-item1" class="device-list-item1" ng-repeat="item in vm.fact_bases" ng-model='vm.fact_bases'>
  <div class="button1 canvas-element canvas-element1" id="{{item.id}}" alert="{{item.alert}}" idFactory="{{item.factory}}" ng-click="deviceSelected(item.id)" ui-sref="app.dashboard.details({transmitterId: item.id, transmitterName: item.id})" style="position: absolute; left: {{item.posx}}px; top: {{item.posy}}px;">
    <div class="dashboard-device-container">
      <div class="icons"><i class="device-icon"></i></div>
      <span class="device_description" ng-bind="item.uiDescription"></span>
      <span class="deviceid" ng-bind="item.id"></span>
      <div class="icons" ng-if="item.alert"><i class="exlhoist-alarm-error-icon"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you please add some CSS so that it will be easier to help.

Comment: and how does it look like on a small desktop browser window size?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy it's working well

Comment: and how do you calculate the `item.posy`?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy those are draggable elements; so I drag them and I drop them into a container that has `relative` position and I store their positions `posx:ui.position.left`, `posy:ui.position.top` so that I can diplay them in the next time when the user logs in

Comment: @MiledBraik aha, I got what you mean, I am trying to think of any reason for your issue, so do you drag drop and save them on the mobile device and on the next load it shows in the wrong position rather than the one you dropped at?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy Yes that's exactly the situation

Comment: if this the situation, so probably the saved y value is wrong on mobile, does it always show on the same position every time? does y get saved with the same value every time?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy I verified the stored values of the position x and y and they are always correct and change whenever I move the element  inside the drop container and it always store the position relativley to the container not all the view so it's not due to the stored values I think

Comment: @MiledBraik I see, trickier than I thought :)